# Livelink ECM 9.x. Why Full Text Search Doesn't work for my document

Tags: full-text-search, ecm

Please explain me how does Full Text Search work in OpenText Livelink ECM?

When I add Microsoft Word document to a folder "Full Text Search" doesn't find it though queried word is the only word in a document

What I do wrong? Or may be I shall wait a bit (how long?) for new document to be indexed?

Answer (score 0):

The default indexing time for a new document is 1 minute.

Do you have any errors in your Enterprise data source or your Admin server?